# Getting jQuery to shift/tab the focus to the next input element on keypress

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I am looking to write a piece of code that will shift/tab the focus of the cursor to the  element in the mark-up if the user presses a key in the previous element.

e.g. each time the user enters a character/digit into a input box the focus automatically tabs to the next input box, like in some serial code input forms.

I have previously tried using jquery's .live and .keypress to no avail. Here is the code I have as of writing this.

```
$('.fmq').keypress(function() {
    $(this).next().focus();
}
```

And here is the markup I have

```
<input name="serial[1]" type="text" maxlength="1" class="fmq">
<input name="serial[2]" type="text" maxlength="1" class="fmq">
<input name="serial[3]" type="text" maxlength="1" class="fmq">
<input name="serial[4]" type="text" maxlength="1" class="fmq">
<input name="serial[5]" type="text" maxlength="1" class="fmq">
<input name="serial[6]" type="text" maxlength="1" class="fmq">
```

Hopefully that is enough information to get the point across, if not then please ask me for more.

Appreciate any help that comes and apologies if this has been posted before.

Cheers,

Dan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't closed your call to `keypress`:

```
$('.fmq').keypress(function() {
    $(this).next().focus();
});
```

That works for me.

Comment: I cannot believe I missed that! :( oh dear, back to coding 101 for me lol. Thank you very much for highlighting the mistake.

Comment: Keep the console window in Firebug or Chrome developer tools open all the time when coding JavaScript. It'll point out obvious bugs like this one.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery UI already has this, in my example below I included a maxchar attribute to focus on the next focus-able element (input, select, textarea, button and object)

```
text 1 <input type="text" value="" id="txt1" maxchar="5" /><br />
text 2 <input type="text" value="" id="txt2" maxchar="5" /><br />
checkbox 1 <input type="checkbox" value="" id="chk1" /><br />
checkbox 2 <input type="checkbox" value="" id="chk2" /><br />
dropdown 1 <select id="dd1" >
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="1">2</option>
</select><br />
dropdown 2 <select id="dd2">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="1">2</option>
</select>


$(function() {
    var focusables = $(":focusable");   
    focusables.keyup(function(e) {
        var maxchar = false;
        if ($(this).attr("maxchar")) {
            if ($(this).val().length >= $(this).attr("maxchar"))
                maxchar = true;
            }
        if (e.keyCode == 13 || maxchar) {
            var current = focusables.index(this),
                next = focusables.eq(current+1).length ? focusables.eq(current+1) : focusables.eq(0);
                next.focus();
        }
    });
});
```